# Angular 2 Input Sanitization

Tags: angular

Is there a straightforward way to implement live sanitization/manipulation of inputs?

Here is an example use case, stripping non-alphabetical characters:

```
<input #fooControl="ngModel"
       name="foo"
       type="text"
       [ngModel]="foo"
       (ngModelChange)="foo = sanitize($event)"
       pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" />
```

-

```
sanitize(val) {
  return val.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, '');
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/W80l2ph8sI8WvCpFkR7a?p=preview

This approach almost works, but when a new sanitized model value is equal to the previous sanitized model value, the input value itself is not updated, displaying unsanitary characters.

I've experimented with https://github.com/msafi/text-mask but the value changes are being done via DOM manipulation and is not compatible with form validation.

This seems like a common requirement and I'm surprised that there isn't native directive for it yet. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `UpgradeAdapter` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) to run run angular 1 alongside angular 2, and then use an angular 1 plugin.